# Cassandra node is unable to start after a HDD failure

Tags: cassandra, recovery, datastax

I have a 5 node Cassandra 2.0.7 cluster, each node has 4 HDDs. Recently one of these HDDs on node3 had failed and was replaced by a new shiny empty drive. After the replacement cassandra on this node was unable to start with this exception:

```
 INFO [main] 2014-06-02 12:45:17,232 ColumnFamilyStore.java (line 254) Initializing system.paxos
 INFO [main] 2014-06-02 12:45:17,236 ColumnFamilyStore.java (line 254) Initializing system.schema_columns
 INFO [SSTableBatchOpen:1] 2014-06-02 12:45:17,237 SSTableReader.java (line 223) Opening /mnt/disk2/cassandra/system/schema_columns/system-schema_columns-jb-310 (25418 bytes)
 INFO [main] 2014-06-02 12:45:17,241 ColumnFamilyStore.java (line 254) Initializing system.IndexInfo
 INFO [main] 2014-06-02 12:45:17,245 ColumnFamilyStore.java (line 254) Initializing system.peers
 INFO [SSTableBatchOpen:1] 2014-06-02 12:45:17,246 SSTableReader.java (line 223) Opening /mnt/disk3/cassandra/system/peers/system-peers-jb-25 (20411 bytes)
 INFO [main] 2014-06-02 12:45:17,253 ColumnFamilyStore.java (line 254) Initializing system.local
 INFO [SSTableBatchOpen:1] 2014-06-02 12:45:17,254 SSTableReader.java (line 223) Opening /mnt/disk3/cassandra/system/local/system-local-jb-35 (80 bytes)
 INFO [SSTableBatchOpen:2] 2014-06-02 12:45:17,254 SSTableReader.java (line 223) Opening /mnt/disk3/cassandra/system/local/system-local-jb-34 (80 bytes)
 ERROR [main] 2014-06-02 12:45:17,361 CassandraDaemon.java (line 237) Fatal exception during initialization
  org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Found system keyspace files, but they couldn't be loaded!
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.SystemKeyspace.checkHealth(SystemKeyspace.java:532)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:233)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:462)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:552)
```

Because of cassandra node being unable to start, I cannot use `nodetool repair`.

The only way I see to recover the node is to remove all data and bootstrap it from nearly bare metal. Is there a shorter way to recover in a typical HDD failure scenario?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Fixed the issue by these steps:

- physically removed files related to `system` keyspace: cassandra was able to start and recreated it, but without any metadata about other keyspaces.
- ran `nodetool resetlocalschema`, which synchronized keyspace schema from other nodes.

Comment: This worked for me as well. For the removal I used: `rm -rf /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/` (CentOS/RHEL)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution I found was to simply delete your data directory within your parent Cassandra directory.  Upon starting Cassandra again it should recreate your namespace.

Comment: But in case if you have multi-HDD setup, single HDD failure can render your node unusable. The question was how to recover node without dropping all the existing data on non-failed HDDs.